# How to change python version of azure function

Tags: python, azure

When I publish my azure cloud functions I get the message:

Local python version '3.9.7' is different from the version expected for your deployed Function App. This may result in 'ModuleNotFound' errors in Azure Functions. Please create a Python Function App for version 3.9 or change the virtual environment on your local machine to match 'Python|3.8'.

How can I change the version to 3.9?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- You can view and set the `linuxFxVersion` from the Azure CLI.
- With the [az functionapp config set command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest), you can change the `linuxFxVersion` setting in the function app.

```
az functionapp config set --name <FUNCTION_APP> \
 --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP> \
 --linux-fx-version "PYTHON|3.9"
```

Please refer [Changing Python version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#changing-python-version) for more information.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I do not have the permission to update config(to python3.9). 
  So I try to install python3.7. And run deployment with `func azure functionapp publish <func_name> --publish-local-settings -i --overwrite-settings -y --python`.  Same error occurred.   
I also got this error message "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].build_summary', line 1, position 663."   
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting '3.9' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you facing the following error when attempting the solution provided by Harshitha:

```
    '3.9' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is because '|' needs to be escaped within the string "PYTHON|3.9" to work in PowerShell. This will work:

`'Python"|"3.9'`

Comment: Tried all escaping methods but command is not recognized. Any other ways to update the version?

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from General Settings under App config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cox3i.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).